# error in a pmap Error in UseMethod("filter_") : no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: r, purrr, pmap

I have written a function that is working fine when I enter the input variables as data frames. But then when I want to use pmap to enter the inputs as a list of data frames I get the following error:

`Error in UseMethod("filter_") :    no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "character"`

Here is the data and the first part of the function that causes the error, I use y and a parameters in parts of the function that is not shown here:

```
x <- tibble::tibble(x1 = sample(0:1, 8, replace = TRUE),
                    x2 = sample(0:25, 8, replace = FALSE),
                    x3 = sample(1:3, 8, replace = TRUE),
                    strata =c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d"))
y <- tibble::tibble(rate = sample(0:1, 8, replace = TRUE),
                    strata =c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d") )

a <- tibble::tibble(sample(10:80, 4, replace = FALSE))
example <- function(x, y, a , d){

  CR <- x %>% filter(x1, x2>0) %>%
    group_by(x3) %>%
    summarise(avg_revenue = mean(x2), revenue = sum(x2))
  return(CR)
}

example(x,y,a, d = 0.1)
```

but when I call the pmap on this function:

```
df <- tibble::tibble(x = x %>% group_by(strata) %>% nest(),
                     y = y %>% group_by(strata) %>% nest(),
                     a = a)
pmap(df, example, d= 0.1)
```

I get the error mentioned above.

Comment: Can you provide data for a minimal reproducible example? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have updated the code so that the error is reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe that `df` is creating the `df` you want it to be creating. I believe this does what you want...if I am understanding the question correctly. However `y` is not used anywhere in your function, so I am unclear what its purpose is. I believe there is also a better way to do this using `map` and `nest` but again I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

```r
library(tidyverse)
x <- tibble::tibble(x1 = sample(0:1, 8, replace = TRUE),
                    x2 = sample(0:25, 8, replace = FALSE),
                    x3 = sample(1:3, 8, replace = TRUE),
                    strata =c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d"))
y <- tibble::tibble(rate = sample(0:1, 8, replace = TRUE),
                    strata =c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d") )

a <- tibble::tibble(a = sample(10:80, 4, replace = FALSE))

example <- function(x, y, a , d){
  CR <- x %>% filter(x1, x2>0) %>%
    group_by(x3) %>%
    summarise(avg_revenue = mean(x2), revenue = sum(x2))
  return(CR)
}

example(x,y,a, d = 0.1)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>      x3 avg_revenue revenue
#>   <int>       <dbl>   <int>
#> 1     1           5      10
df <- bind_cols(x, select(y, rate)) %>% 
  group_by(strata) %>% 
  nest(x = c(x1, x2, x3), 
       y = c(rate)) %>% 
  bind_cols(a) %>% ungroup()
pmap(select(df, -strata), example)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 0 x 3
#> # … with 3 variables: x3 <int>, avg_revenue <dbl>, revenue <int>
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 0 x 3
#> # … with 3 variables: x3 <int>, avg_revenue <dbl>, revenue <int>
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>      x3 avg_revenue revenue
#>   <int>       <dbl>   <int>
#> 1     1           4       4
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>      x3 avg_revenue revenue
#>   <int>       <dbl>   <int>
#> 1     1           6       6
pmap_dfr(select(df, -strata), example, d = 0.1, .id = 'strata')
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   strata    x3 avg_revenue revenue
#>   <chr>  <int>       <dbl>   <int>
#> 1 3          1           4       4
#> 2 4          1           6       6
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This error arises, as CLedbetter has also mentioned in their helpful answer, when the input data-frame to `pmap`,`df`, is not in the correct format. `pmap` expects `df` to only have columns that is known to the function it is operating on.
To that end I edited the `df` with an `inner_join` and then still we have the column `strata` that is not known to the function `example()`.
As it is mentioned in the help of `pmap` function in R in order to make pmap function ignore the column that is not used by function `example()`, 
I used "..." in the definition of `example()` so that pmap can skip the first column of the data-frame, `strata`, that is not used in the function.

So the updated code will be:

```
x <- tibble::tibble(x1 = sample(0:1, 8, replace = TRUE),
                    x2 = sample(0:25, 8, replace = FALSE),
                    x3 = sample(1:3, 8, replace = TRUE),
                    strata =c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d"))
y <- tibble::tibble(rate = sample(0:1, 8, replace = TRUE),
                    strata =c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d") )

a <- tibble::tibble(sample(10:80, 4, replace = FALSE))

# Note the addition of the "..." to the function input definition

example <- function(x, y, a , d, ...){

  CR <- x %>% filter(x1, x2>0) %>%
    group_by(x3) %>%
    summarise(avg_revenue = mean(x2), revenue = sum(x2))
  return(CR)
}

example(x,y,a, d = 0.1)

# Note the change in the reformatting of df with an inner_join

df <- inner_join(x %>% group_by(strata) %>% nest(),
                 y %>% group_by(strata) %>% nest(), 
                 by = "strata") %>% rename(x = data.x, y = data.y )

# with these changes pmap produces the output 
pmap(df, example, d= 0.1)
```